# tomee postconstruct persist database entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-tomee, persist

I'm trying to create an entity as soon as my app starts, to insert the default admin in the database.

```
@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() throws ExternalPartnerException {
    Admin admin = new Admin("admin", "password");

    log.log(Level.INFO, "Default admin initialized");

    entityManager.persist(admin);
}
```

But none of this code seems to be executed, not even the log.
But i know the PostConstruct works because in another class I initialize some attributes in it, and when I didnt do it I had nullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Don't you need a transaction?

Comment: You may need to annotate your bean with `@Transactional`.

Comment: @Startup did it